# receiving error no such file or directory, open 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

i downloaded aws secure socket for my node server and I added it to my index.js folder but i'm getting an error stating Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem.

Does anyone know what maybe causing this error?

heres the code:

```
    var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
const instanceController = require("./asurionController/instanceController")

//keeps data keys hidden from unauth users
require("dotenv").config()

//express Middleware
var helmet = require('helmet'); //creates headers that protect from attacks
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); //parses response
var cors = require('cors'); //allows cross site communication
var morgan = require('morgan'); //logs requests

var app = express();

var db = require("knex")({
    client: "pg",
    connection: {
        database: process.env.DATABASE,
        host: process.env.DBHOST,
        port: process.env.DBPORT,
        user: process.env.DBUSER,
        password: process.env.DBPASSWORD,
        ss1: {
            ss1rootcert: fs.readFileSync("rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem").toString(),
            sslmode: "verify-full"
        }
    }
})

var whitelist = ["http://localhost:3001"];
const corsOptions = {
    origin: function(origin, callback) {
      if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
      }
    }
  };


  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(morgan("combined")); 

  //server connection
  app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000), () =>{
      console.log(`app is running on port ${process.env.port}`|| 5000)
  }"
```

Comment: The file you set to `ss1rootcert` is not found, you have to set the correct place.

Comment: that worked. the file was in the wrong pathway.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it if solved the issue. You can accept an answer by clicking on the check mark of an answer.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the right place to store pem files

Comment: It seems more likely the problem was related to a typo of `ss1` instead of `ssl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you set to `ss1rootcert` is not found, you have to set the correct place.

Change the path of `rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem`:

```
ss1: {
  ss1rootcert: fs.readFileSync("rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem").toString(), // wrong path
  sslmode: "verify-full"
}
```